# How to Save X Y Position Object in Variable and in Array by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

how to put Value for X and Y Position in Variable and Array

object = (XPosition , YPosition)
box_mc.x = 300 , box_mc.y = 200

Comment: You really expect to get an answer? no one can understand what you want.

Comment: @HITMAN : You're right, this is totally unclear.
So my answer is probably useless... :(

Comment: And yet you *have* answered the question that *should* go with the title of this post... so someone may find it useful after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to improve your question.

Is that what you wanna do?

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var p:Point = new Point(200,300);
box_mc.x = p.x;
box_mc.y = p.y;
```

You may also store your values in a bi-dimensional Array as here bellow :

```
var a:Array = [[200,300],[150,200]];
box_mc.x = a[0][0]; //200
box_mc.y = a[0][1]; //300
```

or in this case as you have stored two values for posx and posy :

```
box_mc.x = a[1][0]; //150
box_mc.y = a[1][1]; //200
```

You may also check those links to understand the difference between the different kind of types where you may store values :

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Vectors and ByteArrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/vectors-and-bytearrays.html)

Comment: you tried your best to express the answer he wants. it is still so unclear after an edit.[an upvote].

Comment: In this case, You just have to store the positions for the 9 squares in an Array, then place the squares randomly by using those stored positions.
Just try it, then post your code and someone will help you if you have an issue.
I think that nobody will post the whole code for you if you don't try it by yourself.
Happy to see that the answer may help you to start this project.
Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: You can start by using one Vector for the positions and another Vector for the clips you want to place randomly. As you need only 9 Points and 9 MovieClips you could start to store them like this:

var positions:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>(9);
var squares:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>(9);

Comment: You should definitely avoid Object or Array if the elements stored are made of the same type of Class(es). In this case use the Vector Class instead!

Comment: var arr:Array = new Array();
arr[0] = [78,200] 
arr[1] = [217,200] 
arr[2] = [356,200] 

b1.x = arr[0][0]
b1.y = arr[0][1]

b2.x = arr[1][0]
b2.y = arr[1][1]

b3.x = arr[2][0]
b3.y = arr[2][1]

var rand:Number = (Math.random()*arr.length);


trace(arr)

Comment: Nope, think positions:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>(9);
Then you may store the positions. That's easier and more efficient!

Comment: Try to post another question, try to be more specific.
Post all the code you're able to create.
And the question must be more accurate!
This is the meaning of http://stackoverflow.com ;)

If you don't do this you'll never get help here!- on http://stackoverflow.com Good luck!

Comment: flash.geom.Point is the best way to store positions in a Vector!
Did you check the links I provided about Vector Class???
There's no problem, we try to share knowledge here, but you must be clear!

Comment: Read the FAQ, try to read the help tour before to ask a question!
You will even get a badge :)
Sincerely, Nicolas.

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works, You have to post another question witch includes your code. Everyone will be able to answer. 
I check the new questions each day anyway.
Best regards.