# How to Save positions for 3 objects in Array to make random position between each other by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to Save positions for 3 objects in Array to make random position between each other by AS3?

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var arry:Point = new Point();

arry[0] = arry[78,200];
arry[1] = arry[217,200];
arry[2] = arry[356,200];

//object called b1

b1.x = arry[0][0];
b1.y = arry[0][1];

//object called b2

b2.x = arry[1][0];
b2.y = arry[1][1];

//object called b3

b3.x = arry[2][0];
b3.y = arry[2][1];

//make objects swap positions between each other

var rand:Number = (Math.random()*arry.length);

//output to see random position [[78,200],[217,200],[356,200]]

trace(arry);
```

to get random with tween like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8m_m64plQ6E

Comment: This is a duplicate question and still unclear.
Do You want to do exactly the same thing as in the link you provided or just make 3 Movie clips moving randomly?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375530/how-to-save-x-y-position-object-in-variable-and-in-array-by-as3
This is still unclear.

I've posted another answer on the original post, but as long you don't explain exactly the issue you're facing, it' hard to provide a valid answer

Comment: Your issue is about to swap positions or make those instances move smoothly like in the video???

Comment: Please edit your question, give more information about the problem you're facing.
Is it about swapping positions, find the random Point, or about the tween effect???
If only I could understand, I will post an answer as I told you.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time you should get this Error I suppose : "ReferenceError: Error #1069"
Here is a way to store the positions (like in the link you provided from youtube) :

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var squareWidth:uint = 40;
var squareHeight:uint = 40;
var marginX:uint = 100;
var marginY:uint = 75;
var spacer:uint = 10;
var positions:Vector.<Point >  = new Vector.<Point > (9);

function setPositions(v:Vector.<Point>):void {
    var count:uint = 0;
    var posx:uint;
    var posy:uint;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
        {
            posx = (j * squareWidth) + (spacer * j) + marginX;
            posy = (i * squareHeight) + (spacer * i) + marginY;
            v[count] = new Point(posx,posy);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
setPositions(positions);
trace(positions);
// output : 
// (x=100, y=75),(x=150, y=75),(x=200, y=75),(x=100, y=125),(x=150, y=125),(x=200, y=125),(x=100, y=175),(x=150, y=175),(x=200, y=175)
```

So here you have nine Points to place the clips like in the video.
You just have to add a function to swap the nine boxes stored in another Vector.
In your case.

For 3 positions do the following if I understand your question.

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var positions:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>(3);

var p1:Point = new Point(78,200);
var p2:Point = new Point(217,200);
var p3:Point = new Point(356,200);

positions[0] = p1;
positions[1] = p2;
positions[2] = p3;

trace(positions);

// output : (x=78, y=200),(x=217, y=200),(x=356, y=200)
```

Comment: If you need help, try to read the best way to ask a question in the help page.
This is not a problem to provide you all the code to do the stuff in the youtube link, but on this site you need to be clear and post one question at a time.
I'm not sure that somebody will give you all the code since you have only 3 clips and You don't wanna do exactly the same thing that you posted on the link.
Am I wrong?
For this time I don't give a down vote but try to respect the rules!
Code must be well formatted and a question should concern one problem in your code.
Best regards.

Comment: there are there objects on stage called [b1,b2,b3]  not find in code

Answer (score 0):

So, you're still unclear!
Your issue is to find a random position?

This may help you if this is the problem you're facing :

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var positions:Vector.<Point >  = new Vector.<Point > (3);
var numbers:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();
var numbersAllowed:uint = 3;
var rndNmbrs:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(3);;

var p1:Point = new Point(78,200);
var p2:Point = new Point(217,200);
var p3:Point = new Point(356,200);

positions[0] = p1;
positions[1] = p2;
positions[2] = p3;

trace(positions);

function populateRndNmbrs(n:uint):void {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
}
populateRndNmbrs(numbersAllowed);

function populateRandomNumbers(n:uint):void
{
    var rnd:uint;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rnd = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
        for (var j:uint = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
        {
            if (rnd == numbers[j])
            {
                numbers.splice(j,1);
            }
        }

        rndNmbrs[i] = rnd;
    }
}
populateRandomNumbers(numbersAllowed);
trace("rndNmbrs = " + rndNmbrs);
for (var i:uint = 0; i < numbersAllowed; i++)
{
    trace("b"+ (i+1) + ".x = " + positions[rndNmbrs[i]].x);
    trace("b"+ (i+1) + ".y = " + positions[rndNmbrs[i]].y);
    // In place of trace, you should place the boxes at those random positions.;
}
//output:
//(x=78, y=200),(x=217, y=200),(x=356, y=200)
//rndNmbrs = 2,0,1
//b1.x = 356
//b1.y = 200
//b2.x = 78
//b2.y = 200
//b3.x = 217
//b3.y = 200
```

Is that what you want? Or do you want to know how to create a motion effect?
I'm not sure about what you really need...
This will help you to place all the boxes in a random position.

You may do this like here bellow, and add a function to check if the random positions are not the same.
With only 3 MovieClips, you will often have the same random positions as long they're stored in the "positions Vector"

```
var squares:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>(3);
function populateMCs(target:DisplayObjectContainer,n:uint):void{
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++){
            squares[i] = target["b"+(i+1)];
        }
}
function swapMCs():void{
    for (var i:uint=0; i<squares.length; i++){
        squares[i].x = positions[rndNmbrs[i]].x;
        squares[i].y = positions[rndNmbrs[i]].y;
    }
}
populateMCs(this,numbersAllowed);
swapMCs();
```

Comment: not work b1.x((i+1) + positions[rndNmbrs[i]].x);
    b1.y((i+1) + positions[rndNmbrs[i]].y);  yes I want create motion effect with random

Comment: LIKE this CODE BUT  ITS  AS2 I NEED IT AS3 with motion effect YOU CAN SEE CODE  in description  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMg307X8YKo

Comment: how to add my objects to this code                                                                  trace("b"+ (i+1) + ".x = " + positions[rndNmbrs[i]].x);

Answer (score 0):

I give you a last example to get a motion effect in AS3.
I'm not a translator AS2 -> AS3 and a video is not the best way to show your code :(

This will make your boxes move smoothly, but not the way you want.
Now, you have to learn AS3 and try to make the job by yourself.

Then, if you have another issue, just ask clearly what you want.

```
var friction:Number = 0.15;

setDestination(squares[0],squares[0].x,350,friction);
setDestination(squares[1],squares[1].x,350,friction);
setDestination(squares[2],squares[2].x,350,friction);

squares[0].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveClip);
squares[1].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveClip);
squares[2].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveClip);

function setDestination(mc:MovieClip,x:uint,y:uint,friction:Number):void{
    mc.destinx = x;
    mc.destiny = y;
    mc.f = friction;
}
function moveClip(e:Event):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    trace(mc.name)
    mc.speedx = (mc.destinx - mc.x);
    mc.speedy = (mc.destiny - mc.y);
    mc.x += mc.speedx*mc.f;
    mc.y += mc.speedy*mc.f;
    if((Math.floor(mc.speedx)<1) && (Math.floor(mc.speedy)<1)){
       mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveClip);
       trace("STOP MOVE FOR " + mc.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: all codes unhelpful for me because it's not contain my objects b1 , b2 , b3
just contain trace I dont no where can I put my objects instance name

Comment: @tasha 95 : Like in the video in place of MOVIE1, MOVIE2, MOVIE3. Just change the names to b1, b2, b3.

Comment: No I will not do the work for You.
Try to read the answers I posted.
If you don't understand something post a real question and try to learn the  ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform here :

 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/